# Find number of lines changed between two folders in linux

Tags: linux, grep

So I have a scenario where there are two folders - old and new. old is the older version of a folder and new is the latest version of the folder.

Both of them have same files. But lines have been added, removed or edited in the new version.

I basically want to find the number of lines that have changed in the new folder (lines added, removed or edited - all of these count as lines changed).

I have tried

`diff -y --suppress-common-lines a b | grep '^' | wc -l`

but the value varies when (a = old, b = new) and (a = new, b = old). So I don't think that is the right answer.

What will be the right command in this instance?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Please provide an example. List the file structure and define the differences. Then show the output you get with your described approach and the output you want.